# What are the key under-the-hood concerns handled by d3's animation?

Tags: d3.js

This is really about internals. I wonder what are the main under-the-hood concerns, that d3's animation has to deal with; I mean things like keeping cpu utilization in check, and like keeping the browser responsive to events during the animation, and avoiding display jitter.. What are the "strategies" it employs for those, or other major animation concerns I have left out?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for. The short answer is that D3 uses `requestAnimationFrame()` and everything else is taken care of by the browser. This is [documented](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions).

Comment: Thanks I should probably ask this in a different way, but indeed this paragraph should lead me down the answer https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#timers